# How can I lower the position of a menu a little?

Tags: html, css, nav

I am watching a youtube tutorial, I want to lower the position just a little, I thought it was some type of margin or padding but it does not have. The element I want to lower is `.nav-main ul`
[image]
I want to lower the menu to where the arrows are.

```css
* {
  /*resetear cualquier estilo por defecto */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*para sea de un mismo tamaño siempre */
}

body {
  background-color: #1a181d;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 304 304' width='304' height='304'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23638bc4' fill-opacity='0.4' d='M44.1 224a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-2h44.1zm160 48a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H82v-2h122.1zm57.8-46a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H304v2h-42.1zm0 16a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H304v2h-42.1zm6.2-114a5 5 0 1 1 0 2h-86.2a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h86.2zm-256-48a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-2h12.1zm185.8 34a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h86.2a5 5 0 1 1 0 2h-86.2zM258 12.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V0h2v12.1zm-64 208a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-54.2a5 5 0 1 1 2 0v54.2zm48-198.2V80h62v2h-64V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm16 16V64h46v2h-48V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-128 96V208h16v12.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V210h-16v-76.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-5.9-21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H114v48H85.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H112v-48h12.1zm-6.2 130a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H176v-74.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V242h-60.1zm-16-64a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H114v48h10.1a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H112v-48h-10.1zM66 284.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V274H50v30h-2v-32h18v12.1zM236.1 176a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H226v94h48v32h-2v-30h-48v-98h12.1zm25.8-30a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H274v44.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V146h-10.1zm-64 96a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H208v-80h16v-14h-42.1a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H226v18h-16v80h-12.1zm86.2-210a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H272V0h2v32h10.1zM98 101.9V146H53.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H96v-42.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM53.9 34a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80V0h2v34H53.9zm60.1 3.9V66H82v64H69.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80V64h32V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM101.9 82a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H128V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V82h-28.1zm16-64a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H146v44.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V18h-26.1zm102.2 270a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H98v14h-2v-16h124.1zM242 149.9V160h16v34h-16v62h48v48h-2v-46h-48v-66h16v-30h-16v-12.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM53.9 18a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H64V2H48V0h18v18H53.9zm112 32a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H192V0h50v2h-48v48h-28.1zm-48-48a5 5 0 0 1-9.8-2h2.07a3 3 0 1 0 5.66 0H178v34h-18V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V32h14V2h-58.1zm0 96a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H137l32-32h39V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V66h-40.17l-32 32H117.9zm28.1 90.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-76.51L175.59 80H224V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V82h-49.59L146 112.41v75.69zm16 32a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-99.51L184.59 96H300.1a5 5 0 0 1 3.9-3.9v2.07a3 3 0 0 0 0 5.66v2.07a5 5 0 0 1-3.9-3.9H185.41L162 121.41v98.69zm-144-64a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-3.51l48-48V48h32V0h2v50H66v55.41l-48 48v2.69zM50 53.9v43.51l-48 48V208h26.1a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-65.41l48-48V53.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-16 16V89.41l-34 34v-2.82l32-32V69.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM12.1 32a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H9.41L0 43.41V40.6L8.59 32h3.51zm265.8 18a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h18.69l7.41-7.41v2.82L297.41 50H277.9zm-16 160a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H288v-71.41l16-16v2.82l-14 14V210h-28.1zm-208 32a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H64v-22.59L40.59 194H21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H41.41L66 216.59V242H53.9zm150.2 14a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H96v-56.6L56.6 162H37.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h19.5L98 200.6V256h106.1zm-150.2 2a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80v-46.59L48.59 178H21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H49.41L82 208.59V258H53.9zM34 39.8v1.61L9.41 66H0v-2h8.59L32 40.59V0h2v39.8zM2 300.1a5 5 0 0 1 3.9 3.9H3.83A3 3 0 0 0 0 302.17V256h18v48h-2v-46H2v42.1zM34 241v63h-2v-62H0v-2h34v1zM17 18H0v-2h16V0h2v18h-1zm273-2h14v2h-16V0h2v16zm-32 273v15h-2v-14h-14v14h-2v-16h18v1zM0 92.1A5.02 5.02 0 0 1 6 97a5 5 0 0 1-6 4.9v-2.07a3 3 0 1 0 0-5.66V92.1zM80 272h2v32h-2v-32zm37.9 32h-2.07a3 3 0 0 0-5.66 0h-2.07a5 5 0 0 1 9.8 0zM5.9 0A5.02 5.02 0 0 1 0 5.9V3.83A3 3 0 0 0 3.83 0H5.9zm294.2 0h2.07A3 3 0 0 0 304 3.83V5.9a5 5 0 0 1-3.9-5.9zm3.9 300.1v2.07a3 3 0 0 0-1.83 1.83h-2.07a5 5 0 0 1 3.9-3.9zM97 100a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-48 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 96a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-144a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-96 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm96 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-32 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM49 36a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-32 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM33 68a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 240a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm80-176a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm112 176a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM17 180a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM17 84a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  /*para eliminar cualquier estilo que tenga */
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  /*para que este centrado */
  color: white;
}


/*NAVEGATION*/


/*navegacion completa, incluye los dos menu*/

.nav-main {
  font-size: 17px;
  display: flex;
  /*esto permite ponerlo uno al lado de otro, el logo, el menu, y la busqueda */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*para que use todo el espacio disponible */
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  /*20px arriba y abajo y 0 hacia los lados */
}

.nav-brand {
  width: 50px;
}


/*LEFT NAVIGATION*/

.nav-main ul {
  display: flex;
  /*Para que se pongan cada elemento del menu uno al lado de otro*/
}

.nav-main ul li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-main ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*para quitar raya blanca a los links*/
}

.nav-main ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  padding: 2px;
}


/*acercando el menu al logo*/

.nav-main ul.nav-menu {
  /*como dentro de nav-main hay dos ul, y solo queremos que el menu se acerque al logo, usamos su clase*/
  flex: 0.8;
  /*para posicionar el menu hacia la izquierda*/
  margin-left: 25px;
}


/*SHOW CASE*/

.showcase {
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background: url("img/showcase2.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
  /*esto hace que la imagen este centrada y se ajuste el tama;o para que se muestre completa*/
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.showcase p {
  padding: 20px;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: rgb(88, 14, 14);
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tecnews</title>
  <!--Estilos CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!--GOOGLE FONTS-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Font awesome-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav-main">
      <img src="img\brand.png" alt="tecnews logo" class="nav-brand">
      
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Web develoment</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Cripto</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Machine learning</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Updated News</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">More</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <ul class="nav-menu-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#"> <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <hr>
    
    <!--SHOW CASE-->
    <header class="showcase">
      <h2>Big news Today!!</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus voluptatibus porro veniam cupiditate. Repudiandae saepe animi mollitia qui dolore, accusantium asperiores dolores nesciunt ad. Id similique iure dolore earum magni.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Learn More <i class="fa-solid fa-angles-right"></i></a>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the property `margin-top` to the rule whose selector is `.nav-main ul`.

Here is an example with `margin-top: 30px` :

```css
*{
    /*resetear cualquier estilo por defecto */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;  /*para sea de un mismo tamaño siempre */
}

body{
    background-color: #1a181d;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 304 304' width='304' height='304'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23638bc4' fill-opacity='0.4' d='M44.1 224a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-2h44.1zm160 48a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H82v-2h122.1zm57.8-46a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H304v2h-42.1zm0 16a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H304v2h-42.1zm6.2-114a5 5 0 1 1 0 2h-86.2a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h86.2zm-256-48a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-2h12.1zm185.8 34a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h86.2a5 5 0 1 1 0 2h-86.2zM258 12.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V0h2v12.1zm-64 208a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-54.2a5 5 0 1 1 2 0v54.2zm48-198.2V80h62v2h-64V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm16 16V64h46v2h-48V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-128 96V208h16v12.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V210h-16v-76.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-5.9-21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H114v48H85.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H112v-48h12.1zm-6.2 130a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H176v-74.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V242h-60.1zm-16-64a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H114v48h10.1a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H112v-48h-10.1zM66 284.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V274H50v30h-2v-32h18v12.1zM236.1 176a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H226v94h48v32h-2v-30h-48v-98h12.1zm25.8-30a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H274v44.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V146h-10.1zm-64 96a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H208v-80h16v-14h-42.1a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H226v18h-16v80h-12.1zm86.2-210a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H272V0h2v32h10.1zM98 101.9V146H53.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H96v-42.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM53.9 34a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80V0h2v34H53.9zm60.1 3.9V66H82v64H69.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80V64h32V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM101.9 82a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H128V37.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V82h-28.1zm16-64a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H146v44.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0V18h-26.1zm102.2 270a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H98v14h-2v-16h124.1zM242 149.9V160h16v34h-16v62h48v48h-2v-46h-48v-66h16v-30h-16v-12.1a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM53.9 18a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H64V2H48V0h18v18H53.9zm112 32a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H192V0h50v2h-48v48h-28.1zm-48-48a5 5 0 0 1-9.8-2h2.07a3 3 0 1 0 5.66 0H178v34h-18V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V32h14V2h-58.1zm0 96a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H137l32-32h39V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V66h-40.17l-32 32H117.9zm28.1 90.1a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-76.51L175.59 80H224V21.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0V82h-49.59L146 112.41v75.69zm16 32a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-99.51L184.59 96H300.1a5 5 0 0 1 3.9-3.9v2.07a3 3 0 0 0 0 5.66v2.07a5 5 0 0 1-3.9-3.9H185.41L162 121.41v98.69zm-144-64a5 5 0 1 1-2 0v-3.51l48-48V48h32V0h2v50H66v55.41l-48 48v2.69zM50 53.9v43.51l-48 48V208h26.1a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H0v-65.41l48-48V53.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zm-16 16V89.41l-34 34v-2.82l32-32V69.9a5 5 0 1 1 2 0zM12.1 32a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H9.41L0 43.41V40.6L8.59 32h3.51zm265.8 18a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h18.69l7.41-7.41v2.82L297.41 50H277.9zm-16 160a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H288v-71.41l16-16v2.82l-14 14V210h-28.1zm-208 32a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H64v-22.59L40.59 194H21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H41.41L66 216.59V242H53.9zm150.2 14a5 5 0 1 1 0 2H96v-56.6L56.6 162H37.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2h19.5L98 200.6V256h106.1zm-150.2 2a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H80v-46.59L48.59 178H21.9a5 5 0 1 1 0-2H49.41L82 208.59V258H53.9zM34 39.8v1.61L9.41 66H0v-2h8.59L32 40.59V0h2v39.8zM2 300.1a5 5 0 0 1 3.9 3.9H3.83A3 3 0 0 0 0 302.17V256h18v48h-2v-46H2v42.1zM34 241v63h-2v-62H0v-2h34v1zM17 18H0v-2h16V0h2v18h-1zm273-2h14v2h-16V0h2v16zm-32 273v15h-2v-14h-14v14h-2v-16h18v1zM0 92.1A5.02 5.02 0 0 1 6 97a5 5 0 0 1-6 4.9v-2.07a3 3 0 1 0 0-5.66V92.1zM80 272h2v32h-2v-32zm37.9 32h-2.07a3 3 0 0 0-5.66 0h-2.07a5 5 0 0 1 9.8 0zM5.9 0A5.02 5.02 0 0 1 0 5.9V3.83A3 3 0 0 0 3.83 0H5.9zm294.2 0h2.07A3 3 0 0 0 304 3.83V5.9a5 5 0 0 1-3.9-5.9zm3.9 300.1v2.07a3 3 0 0 0-1.83 1.83h-2.07a5 5 0 0 1 3.9-3.9zM97 100a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-48 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 96a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-144a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-96 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm96 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-32 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM49 36a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-32 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM33 68a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 240a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm80-176a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 48a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm112 176a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-16 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM17 180a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0 16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm0-32a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16 0a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zM17 84a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm32 64a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm16-16a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

a{
    color: white;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;   /*para eliminar cualquier estilo que tenga */

}

.container{
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto; /*para que este centrado */
    color: white;
}

/*NAVEGATION*/
/*navegacion completa, incluye los dos menu*/
.nav-main{
    font-size: 17px;
    display: flex;   /*esto permite ponerlo uno al lado de otro, el logo, el menu, y la busqueda */
    justify-content: space-between; /*para que use todo el espacio disponible */
    height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 0px; /*20px arriba y abajo y 0 hacia los lados */
   
}

.nav-brand{
    width: 50px;
}

/*LEFT NAVIGATION*/

.nav-main ul{
    display: flex; /*Para que se pongan cada elemento del menu uno al lado de otro*/
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav-main ul li{
    padding: 10px;
    
}

.nav-main ul li a{
    text-decoration: none; /*para quitar raya blanca a los links*/
}

.nav-main ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    padding: 2px;
}

/*acercando el menu al logo*/
.nav-main ul.nav-menu{         /*como dentro de nav-main hay dos ul, y solo queremos que el menu se acerque al logo, usamos su clase*/
    flex: 0.8;  /*para posicionar el menu hacia la izquierda*/
    margin-left: 25px;

}

/*SHOW CASE*/

.showcase{
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background: url("img/showcase2.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover; /*esto hace que la imagen este centrada y se ajuste el tama;o para que se muestre completa*/
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.showcase p{
    padding: 20px;
}

.btn{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: rgb(88, 14, 14);
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.btn:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tecnews</title>
    <!--Estilos CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--GOOGLE FONTS-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Font awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="nav-main">
            <img src="img\brand.png" alt="tecnews logo" class="nav-brand">
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Web develoment</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Cripto</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Machine learning</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Updated News</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">More</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="nav-menu-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <hr>
        <!--SHOW CASE-->
        <header class="showcase">
            <h2>Big news Today!!</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus voluptatibus porro veniam cupiditate. Repudiandae saepe animi mollitia qui dolore, accusantium asperiores dolores nesciunt ad. Id similique iure dolore earum magni.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Learn More <i class="fa-solid fa-angles-right"></i></a>
        </header>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```